# Convertir tipo de dato Time HH:MM:SS a Date Time Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, datetime

Recibo de un API un dato `String` (originalmente `time` en la base de datos), que me proporciona una hora de la siguiente forma:

`17:30:00`

Quiero que solo muestre `17:30`, pero trato de convertir el `string` a `DateTime` y me regresa el siguiente error:
`FormatException (FormatException: Invalid date format 17:30:00)`

Tengo un método que recibe el dato en tipo `String`, y debería hacer la conversión y regresarme el formato deseado, en la línea de `final parsearTiempo` es donde se presenta el error:

```
    String convertirTiempo(String tiempo){
      String time = tiempo;
      String? tiempoFinal;
      
      final parsearTiempo = DateTime.parse(time);
      DateFormat('Hm').format(parsearTiempo);
      tiempoFinal = parsearTiempo.toString();
      return tiempoFinal;
    }
```

Muestro el dato en pantalla de la siguiente forma:

```
Text(
  convertirTiempo(snapshot.data![index].ExitTime),
  style: const TextStyle(
  fontSize: 16.0,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
),
```

Comment: Es similar al ejemplo anterior

Comment: Si, pero al intentar darle formato a la hora, me dice que la hora que me manda el API (17:30:00) no es válido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que el `DateTime.parse` solo funciona con variables `String` que contenga un `patron` de una fecha completa, en tu caso solo estás enviando la hora, minutos y millisegundos, estuve buscando en pub.dev a ver si encontraba algún paquete, pero no pude encontrar, así que lo que hice, fue similar a una de tus preguntas anteriores, solo que usando un `split` que nos permitirá transformar esta cadena de texto a una `lista` y así poder separar las partes que nos interesan, en este caso las dos primeras posiciones, aquí te dejo el ejemplo:

```
 String convertirHora(String hora) {
    final tiempo = hora.split(':');
    //debugPrint(tiempo.toString());

    String tiempoFinal = "${tiempo[0]}:${tiempo[1]}";

    debugPrint(tiempoFinal);
    //resultado= 17:30

    return tiempoFinal;
  }
```